# Unable to print the output

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hello I am trying to scrape a website as a part of it I have written the first code snippet to see I can print the URLS but I am unable to do so, where am I going wrong? Please help

```
import requests
from time import sleep

def get_html(url):
    response=requests.get(url)
    if not response.ok:
        print(f"Code: {response.status_code}, url:{url}")
    return response.text



def main():
    start = 1
    url = 'https://www.vivo.com/in/support/queryProductInfosByClassifyId?classifyId={start}'

    while True:

        print(url)

        if True:
            start +=1
            url = 'https://www.vivo.com/in/support/queryProductInfosByClassifyId?classifyId={start}'
        else:
            break
            


        sleep(0.3)




if __name__ == ' __main__ ':
    main()
```

Comment: you are never calling the `get_html` function.

Comment: You shouldn't use `while True` and `break`. You should create a boolean variable instead

Comment: What does "unable to do so" mean? Are the wrong urls printed? Is nothing printed at all? Are only some urls printed? We need more details to be able to help

Comment: @joshmeranda sir no output is printed